Fastlane TestFlight Submit for Review
I use Fastlane in my Unity project to auto upload to TestFlight when Unity Build Automation finishes.
I currently have two issues:

Even though I use a csv file to specify testing groups, it's not being set in TestFlight.
I want to be able to auto submit for review with a default answer for the radio selection but I apparently don't know how to do that.


pilot(api_key: lane_context[SharedValues::APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY],
      app_version: "1."+options[:number], build_number: options[:number]+".1",
      changelog: options[:changes],
      uses_non_exempt_encryption: true,
      groups: ["group1,group2"],
      beta_app_description: "Description",
      beta_app_feedback_email: "e@mail.com",
      ipa: "/path/to/file.ipa") --verbose

I was expecting to have the build to show in my dashboard with the groups already set and just waiting for review. I still get this window and no groups.

